# iPhone dev question: "No provisioned iPhone OS is connected" error, I don't know what else to try for troubleshooting

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to compile and install my first application onto my iPhone after setting up a profile and certificate. At this point I am getting the "No provisioned iPhone OS is connected" error when I Build & Go.

I am using iPhone OS 3.1.3, and Xcode 3.2.2 on 10.6.3.

• I have verified that my iPhone is connected to my development machine (it is seen on the computer by both iTunes and Xcode Organizer (in Organizer, it has the green dot next to it)).

• I have rebooted the iPhone and restarted Xcode multiple times.

• I have verified that the Bundle Identifier in my appname.plist is set to com.. (with the appropriate values between the angle brackets).

I have looked the error message up on the web, and so far have not found a hint that has gotten me over the hump....

Thanks for any and all assistance!

Regards,

Steve O'Sullivan

Comment: Is your profile included in Organizer->Provisioning Profiles ?
And did you install your certificate like it's written in the Provisioning Profile Wizard, etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open **Organizer** (in Xcode > Window >
   Organizer) check whether there is a
   green dot next to your iPhone.
2. Click on the iPhone item, check whether it's ready for development (if "Use for development" is there, that means not)
3. Sometimes, you may need to power off then on your iPhone

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the UDID of the device to the relevant provisioning profile on the Apple iPhone developer portal, and downloaded and installed the new profile?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an answer now; see comment below.  But if nothing else, an identical problem and question.  I've tried all of the unique suggestions made on this and other forums, several times for some suggestions, as the original author has done, and I continue to get the same message.  I've removed everything from the provisioning portal, from my iPhone (3.1.3), and from XCode (3.2), and rebuilt/reinstalled everything.  As above, the green dot shows in the Organizer as does the relevant iPhone specific data, the provisioning file is there and on the iPhone, all the appropriate certificates appear to be in place.  I've "clean"ed the build; I've turned the iPhone off and restarted XCode, in several different sequences; I shut down the development Mac and restarted everything.  But, I continue to get the "No provisioned iPhone OS device is connected".

And, yes, this is my first try at loading a development application to the iPhone, so the original question's author and I seem to share similar relevant experience and behavior.  I keep hoping to go back and find a missing step.  And, while it did take several tries to get to this point, with everything looking like it's right, it appears I've still overlooked something important.

Beyond the "restart" suggestions, has anyone found any strong sensitivities to the order in which things are done, or anything that seems to have become more difficult with XCode 3.2 or iPhone 3.1.3?  I notice that the many examples of this question first appeared 18 months ago, then it was silent for quite a while, and now there's been a slew of new queries of this kind.

Comment: Here's the start of an answer, for my problem at least, and perhaps for dsobol's situation.  I found this in the Apple Developer Forum.  In the Target "info" page, there's an item in "Deployment: Targeted Device Family".  In my info it was set to iPad, though I was downloading to an iPhone.  Changing that to "iPhone/iPad", and then changing "Architectures:Architectures" to Arm6/Arm7 gets me to a new failure message, since I'm using an iPhone 3G - Arm7 by itself doesn't work.  I've got to research the latest error message to work through that failure mechanism.

Comment: OK, here's the rest of the answer to my problem.  After the above, the error message was that there was no valid provisioning for the app.  It appeared as though there were, but after repeated attempts, I deleted the provision for it, created a wild card provision, and installed that.  The app finally loaded, then.  Haven't tried a second one, but suspect this will now work for all.